# Use of "Vie sociale"

Tags: anglais, expressions

Like in English “He doesn't have a social life”, is it normal to say in French “il n'a pas une vie sociale“? What is a better phrase for the same type of expression?

Comment: “Il n'a pas de vie sociale” would be a more accurate translation, and can be used in French. It means exactly the same, however I don't know why, to my ear, the English version sounds joke-ish while the French one sounds grave…

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Thanks so much. You could have given this as an answer and I would done an upvote. No, in English it's not jokish. It's a negetive expression to signify an introvert.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez though I have upvoted your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the phrase *vie sociale* would be understood, but it is not idiomatic. I would say

> Il n'a pas de vie.

The meaning is subtly dependent on the context. For example, “*ce n'est pas une vie*” means “this is no way to live”, i.e. there's something wrong with my lifestyle (which is usually not something I can fix); while the absence of a social life is often an aspect of this, it is not the primary meaning.

I think I would more spontaneously use other ways of phrasing “he doesn't have a social life”, not using the word *vie*:

> Il ne sort pas.
>   Il reste dans son coin.

Comment: perfect explaination.

Comment: I would translate "Il n'a pas de vie" (idiomatically) as, "He needs to get a life." But the translation "does the job."